# Trocar uma variável de True para False e vice-versa

Tags: android, android-studio

Criei um botão que quando é clicado cria o metodo onClick e torna uma variável "true"

O que quero é que se esse botão for clicado novamente e a variável ja for true ela vire "false"

estou usando o Android Studio, alguma luz?

Comment: se não me engano, vc pode usar arrays, e alternar de true para false sempre que apertar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um simples

```
variavel = !variavel;
```

dentro do seu listener resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

tem várias meneiras de se fazer isso,mas tenta isso assim ó:

```
public class mycActivity ... {
  boolean vaiserfalsedepois = false;
  // ...
  meubotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        vaiserfalsedepois = !vaiserfalsedepois;
        // ou 
        if (vaiserfalsedepois === true)
           vaiserfalsedepois = false;
        else
           vaiserfalsedepois = true;
         // e por ai vai
     }
  });
}
```

espero que ajude!

luz e paz!

Comment: Entendi, então dentro do metodo OnCreate para o text do botão mudar de acordo com a variavel seria:  if (vaiserfalsedepois) {

            botaoid.setText("Verdadeiro");
        }

        else {
            botaoid.setText("falso");


        } ?

Comment: opa, dai é diferente, dai voce pode setar uma variável texto inicada com "Falso" por ex, e mudar para "Verdadeiro" diretamente no listener, salvo se voce precisar mesmo de uma variavel booleana, senão, tenta algo assim:
`String tvar = null; tvar = vclicado.equals("verdadeiro")?"Falso":"Verdadeiro";`
fica mais fácil e voce evita o if ... else

Comment: ops, tem de setar o valor do texto do botão com o valor de tvar depois, ririri, foi maus, para isso faça `meubotao.setText(tvar);` e voilá

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado!!!